# CrossTabs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am wondering how can I create Cross Tabs queries with SQL Server 2008. I have fields for Job Numbers and Employees and I want to show that how many hours an Employee has worked on the specific job.

Here is the query.

```
SELECT Ename, JobNum, LaborHrs
FROM CombinedLabor
```

which will return the list of employee name, with job nums and labor hrs.

The existing table is as follows:

```
ENAME   JOBNUM    LABORHRS
abc      N6880       8.0
abc      N6880       2.5  
xyz      N7860       9.5
...      ...         ...
```

So I want something like this

```
        N6880 N7860 ... Total Hrs
abc     10.5   0.0     ... 10.5
xyz      0.0   9.5      ... 9.5
```

I tried `PIVOT` but that didn't work for. Later I want to export this data to EXCEL with C#.

**EDIT**

Okay here is the query.

`SELECT Ename, JobNum,LaborHrs FROM CombinedLabor` which will return the list of employee name, with job nums and labor hrs.

The existing table is as follows:

```
ENAME   JOBNUM    LABORHRS
abc      N6880       8.0
abc      N6880       2.5  
xyz      N7860       9.5
...      ...         ...
```

So I want something like this

```
        N6880 N7860 ... Total Hrs
abc     10.5   0.0     ... 10.5
xyz     0.0   9.5      ... 9.5
```

Comment: what do your existing tables with this information look like? And I'm assuming by 'how many hours' a SUM of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @CombinedLabor TABLE
  ( 
   ENAME varchar(50)
  ,JOBNUM varchar(20)
  ,LABORHRS decimal(10,2)
  )

INSERT  INTO @CombinedLabor
        ( ENAME, JOBNUM, LABORHRS )
VALUES  ( 'abc', 'N6880', 8.0 )
,       ( 'abc', 'N6880', 2.5 )
,       ( 'abc', 'N6881', 5.2 )
,       ( 'xyz', 'N7860', 9.5 ) ;  

SELECT
   ENAME
  ,SUM(CASE JOBNUM WHEN 'N6880' THEN LABORHRS ELSE 0 END) AS [N6880]
  ,SUM(CASE JOBNUM WHEN 'N6881' THEN LABORHRS ELSE 0 END) AS [N6881]
  ,SUM(CASE JOBNUM WHEN 'N7860' THEN LABORHRS ELSE 0 END) AS [N7860]
  ,SUM(LABORHRS) AS [PersonTotal]
FROM   @CombinedLabor
GROUP BY ENAME
```

And the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try doing your cross tab manipulation in C#:

http://code.google.com/p/pivot-tools/

I suspect you'll find it easier than fiddling with a dynamic pivot. (This is my project, so let me know if you have any questions.)

---

Before doing that, you might want to retrieve "Total Hrs" in advance, like so:

```
SELECT Ename, JobNum, SUM(LaborHrs) LaborHrs, TotalHrs
FROM CombinedLabor
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Ename, SUM(LaborHrs) TotalHrs
FROM CombinedLabor
GROUP BY EName
) Totals
ON CombinedLabor.Ename = Totals.Ename
GROUP BY CombinedLabor.Ename, JobNum, TotalHrs
```

(A suggestion: Different employees could have the same name, so you should have an id column to join on.)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @CombinedLabor TABLE
  ( 
   ENAME varchar(50)
  ,JOBNUM varchar(20)
  ,LABORHRS decimal(10,2)
  )

INSERT  INTO @CombinedLabor
        ( ENAME, JOBNUM, LABORHRS )
VALUES  ( 'abc', 'N6880', 8.0 )
,       ( 'abc', 'N6880', 2.5 )
,       ( 'abc', 'N6881', 5.2 )
,       ( 'xyz', 'N7860', 9.5 ) ;  

SELECT ENAME
    ,isnull([N6880], 0) [N6880]
    ,isnull([N6881], 0) [N6881]
    ,isnull([N7860], 0) [N7860]
    ,TotalHrs
FROM (
    SELECT ENAME
        ,JOBNUM
        ,LABORHRS
        ,sum(LABORHRS) OVER (PARTITION BY ENAME) TotalHrs
    FROM @CombinedLabor
    ) a
PIVOT(sum(LABORHRS) FOR JOBNUM IN (
            [N6880]
            ,[N6881]
            ,[N7860]
            )) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY ENAME
```